# Visual Studio Code error "Windows cannot find...iexplore.exe"

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, visual-studio-code

I have been using VS Code on my MBP for a month or so without issue.

I have now also installed it on my Win10 workstation.

When I press ctrl-shift-p to bring up the command palette I receive an error dialog

`"Windows cannot find 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe". Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.`

The [Visual Studio Code System Requirements](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements) do not indicate a requirement for iexplore.exe.

A little google-fu exercise brings me to [defkey.com's list](https://defkey.com/what-means/ctrl-shift-p) of programs that use ctrl-shift-p, and nothing listed triggers iexplore.exe.

The error is not incorrect, as I have removed Internet Explorer from every Windows installation I've performed since Win7 was released, and I have no interest in adding it back to the install.

Is this this just a fluke with my install (which I have removed and re-installed), or is IE actually required by VS Code?

Any ideas on how I can fix ctrl-shift-p to open the command palette without installing IE?

Comment: Have a look here under advanced customization....https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Answer (score 0):

I have realized that although the issue is only manifesting itself in VS Code because of VS Code's usage of ctrl + shift + p, this shortcut is attempting to open iexplore.exe even when VS Code is not open and thus is a system keyboard shortcut and issue, and not a problem that VS Code can fix.

@Moab I appreciate your efforts to assist.